# Using a CASE Statement to search only the Time in DateTime Format

Tags: sql, casting, case, between

I have a datetime column that I would like to use a case statement to rename a new column based on the time in the datetime column.

```
select *,
       (case when CONVERT(varchar,date_time,14) between '00:00:00.000' and '12:00:00.000'
            then '0-12' else date_time end) as 'TIME'
```

From.....
I have tried this many ways with CAST and CONVERT and even with syntax is correct, I get the error:

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

A `case` **expression** returns a single value.  And that value has a single type.  The SQL compiler must decide what the type is.  You have:

- A string for the `THEN` clause.
- A `datetime` for the `ELSE` clause.

The compiler decides that the expression returns a `datetime` -- by the rules of SQL.  SQL cannot convert `'0-12'` to a date/time, so it returns a conversion error.

I don't know what you really want to do, because you haven't provided sufficient explanation.  You may just want to convert the `date_time` value to a string to solve this problem.